# How to handle number format of OData Edm.Decimal in sapui5 correct?

Tags: odata, number-formatting, sapui5

It looks like OData sends Edm.Decimal as "String" also containing the decimal separator.

Question: What should be send by OData? Always the same values (for example separator with ".")?

Question: How can this data be bound to SAPUI5 control with an automatic locale handling?

I am already using

```
new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
```

But numbers are always shown with a dot as separator.

Comment: in my opinion, you can't handle it other than using strings. but would be glad to find a solution.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid usage of manually implemented type formatter? I would expect that SAPUI5 could format values automatically depending on the used language. In that case the only thing to program should be "this is a float" but not specifying separators? I am still searching SAPUI5 schooling documents but have not found any solution yet :-/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in `sap.ui.model.type.Float` implementation.
You can use that data type to format decimal values.

But if you try to change the value and store it back, data will be of type float. But for OData it must be a String.

Debugging the method `parserValue` gives me the hint:

```
case "string":
    iResult = this.oFormat.parse(oValue);
    ... error handling ...
    return iResult;
```

The `iResult` will not be transformed to a String if it is not already a string. You can override that method and ensure that it will return a string.